# Capitalizing value labels in Stata

Tags: stata

Some datasets come with full-lowercase value labels, and I end up with graphs and tables showing results for "egypt", "jordan" and "saudi arabia" instead of the capitalized country names.

I guess that the `proper()` string function can do something for me, but I am not finding the right way to write the code for Stata 11 that will capitalize all value labels for a given variable.

I basically need to run the `proper()` function on all value labels on the variable, and then assign them to the variable. Is that possible using a `foreach` loop and macros in Stata?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  First let's create some sample data with labels for testing:

```
clear
drawnorm x, n(10)
gen byte v = int(4+x)
drop x
label define types 0 "zero" 1 "one" 2 "two" 3 "three" 4 "four" 5 "five" 6 "six"
label list types
label values v types
```

Here's a macro to capitalize the values associated with the variable "v":

```
local varname v
local sLabelName: value label `varname'
di "`sLabelName'"

levelsof `varname', local(xValues)
foreach x of local xValues {
    local sLabel: label (`varname') `x', strict
    local sLabelNew =proper("`sLabel'")
    noi di "`x': `sLabel' ==> `sLabelNew'"
    label define `sLabelName' `x' "`sLabelNew'", modify
}
```

After running it, check the results:

```
label list types
```